# How do I have MuseScore continue notes in bass clef thats are input in treble clef?

Tags: notation, musescore

I am trying to input this:

[image: photograph of notes]

But in MuseScore, I get this:

[image: actual notes]

The note will not become a continuation of the already played notes in the treble clef.

Why not?

## edit

This question is already answered, but to conclude the solution, I need to add a beam between an eight note and a sixteenth note. What I got now is this.

[image: notes without a beam between eigth note and sixteenth note]

It would be more pleasant looking and like the original if that beam is there.

## edit 2

I got another excellent answer. By selecting the first 16th note, going to beam properties (in the accordion to the left) and selecting this kind of beam property

[image: beam property number two]

I get this result

[image: result after joining beams]

Now, how do I have all stems pointing upwards?

I tried to use the inspector to the right, selecting each of the notes (the dot part) and selecting stem direction up.

[image: selecting one note]

[image: setting for stem direction]

Without being able to change the stem direction.

Selecting the stems themselves gives me no direction setting in the inspector.

[image: inspector after selecting the stem]

## edit 3

I got a comment that I should double click the beam and then select one note and then move that note.

After double clicking the beam:

[image: After double clicking the beam]

After clicking a note once:

[image: After clicking a note once]

(no visual feedback that I clicked the note)

After trying to click it again

[image: after clicking the note yet another time]

The feedback that I double clicked the beam has dissapeared. I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, you should be able to doubleclick the beam, select one of the nodes, and move it up.

Comment: I edited my question @Richard

Comment: When you doubleclick the beam, select one of the square nodes (not notes!) that appears on either side of the beam. Then try to move that up and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Richard that was awesome! If you make that an answer, I upvote it.

Comment: Ah, I'll just edit my original answer. Glad to help, and welcome to [music.se]!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We call this “cross-staff notation” if this helps you in future searches. The steps:

1. Write all necessary pitches in one staff. In your case, write all upstem notes in the upper staff.
2. Now select the note that needs to be moved.
3. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-*Direction* (on Mac it's <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-*Direction*), where “*Direction*” is the up or down arrow depending on where you want the pitch(es) to move. In your case, you’ll be shifting these down, so hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Tips on any necessary beaming adjustments are available [on MuseScore's website](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/cross-staff-notation).

---

**Edit Addressing OP's Edits**

In order to change the entire beamed group to be upstem notes, you must:

1. Doubleclick the beam.
2. Select one of the square nodes that appears on either side of the beam. (Nodes, not notes!)
3. Move the selected node up or down to match the desired beaming.

Comment: Yeah, one of the things with MuseScore is that there are a lot of more advanced features that are only available as keyboard shortcuts. The only way I ever learned about them was googling how to do something I couldn't easily see how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Select the first 16th notes, go to "Beam Properties" and double-click the second option. Should take care of you. By the way, MuseScore has its own forums that are more adapted to back-and-forth problem-solving like this.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me forward and  giving the tip of using the MuseScore forum.

Comment: However, posts in the MuseScore forum seems to be uneditable after a while (12 hours) for no reason so I probably stick to Stack Exchange.